# Can separate network segments connected by a router be considered on the same segment?

Tags: networking, router

Say you have two or more network segments that are connected by a router, or perhaps multiple segments connected by multiple routers connected together by a router. Would the devices on the aforementioned segments be considered on the same network segment?

Comment: `Would the devices on the aforementioned segments be considered on the same network segment?` - No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can separate network segments connected by a router be considered on the same segment?

No. Generally when we say a segment we mean a broadcast domain, when routing between multiple segments inherently means you're not talking about a single broadcast domain/segment.