# Are devices on the same VLAN considered on the same network segment?

Tags: networking, vlan

Say you have two network segments connected by a router. In my [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1008191/can-separate-network-segments-connected-by-a-router-be-considered-on-the-same-se/1008200#1008200) we found that the two network segments are not on the same network segment when connected by a router. Now say you put the two aforementioned network segments in the same VLAN. Would the two network segments in the VLAN be considered on the same network segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point of the answer to your previous question is the concept of [broadcast domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain), i.e. the set of network nodes (endpoints and switches), which are reachable by broadcast messages at the data link layer (OSI layer 2, e.g. Ethernet). You have two broadcast domains.

[VLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN) technologies (like [IEEE 802.1Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q)) allow you to further **divide** your broadcast domain into smaller ones. So you can have several *virtual* broadcast domains for each *physical* broadcast domain, but they don't span beyond the physical domain.

If you join two VLANs (either on different or the same physical network) using a **router** (which works at OSI layer 3), they will still be **separate** broadcast domains. You need to connect them using a **bridge** (which works at OSI layer 2 and is a special kind of switch) if you want to join them into a **single** network segment.

Summarizing:

- network segments, broadcast domains and VLANs are **Layer 2** concepts and you can enlarge them with **switches** (or **bridges** which are switches with 2 ports),
- **routers** (or **gateways** which are routers with 2 interfaces) join different network segments into on network: e.g. the Internet or all those private networks deployed in people's homes and companies.